# Could any one advice how to set field type as Number for a particular field

Tags: java, excel

Here am Generating a `xlsx` file using `xssfworkbook` in java, Its getting data from DB and store in the excel.

Query is : `select name , place, ROUND(amount, 2) as amount from table_name`
in above query amount need to be store in excel as Number, so that i can do calculations instead manually changing type after generate excel.

Java Code :

```java
for (String key : keyset)
{
    Row row = sheet.createRow(rownum++);
    List<String> objArr = data.get(key);
    int cellnum = 0;
    for (Object obj : objArr)
    {
        Cell cell = row.createCell(cellnum++);
         if(rownum == 1)
         {
                cell.setCellStyle(style1);
                if(obj instanceof String)
                    cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                else if(obj instanceof Integer)
                    cell.setCellValue((Integer)obj);
         }
         else
         {
             if(obj instanceof String)
                    cell.setCellValue((String)obj);
                else if(obj instanceof Integer)
                    cell.setCellValue((Integer)obj);
         }
    }

}
```

Comment: Any attempt to provide some formatting? And you'd probably want to put some more effort into the question as well, e.g. I'm not sure I understand what you're asking about.

Answer (score 0):

It seem you want to set the type of a cell when you have an int so in your instance check

```
if(obj instanceof Integer){
    cell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC);
}
```